# how to request to a remote server with cookies included (PHP/javascript)

Tags: php, cookies, httprequest

I want to send a request including cookies to a HTTP website.

How I can do this?

I sent a request without cookies as a first-time visit and tracked the header there was a cookie inside responded header like this:

```
Set-cookie: ERIGHTS=VQPFIWEdiYEtW4Eko2T3bikz4H2dDx2FtH-zlTTRFyzW+urkCU7bwGj2w==
Set-cookie: WLSESSION=1512202892.20480.0000
```

Now how I can send a new request with theses cookies included?

Comment: posted my answer too soon :) what technology are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [PHP's cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), you can do that and much more with it.

- [Using Cookies with cURL](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/04/php-curl-fetching-url-and-sending-request-with-cookies.html)

Comment: thanks, is there any brief tutorial with php examples for using cURL ? please help

Comment: You'll find plenty with Google. And one is on the second link (the one Gordon added)

Answer (score 0):

The counterpart of the response header field *Set-Cookie* is the request header field *Cookie*. So the request header with that cookies could look like this:

```
Cookie: ERIGHTS=VQPFIWEdiYEtW4Eko2T3bikz4H2dDx2FtH-zlTTRFyzW+urkCU7bwGj2w==, WLSESSION=1512202892.20480.0000
```

Comment: the header says : 
Set-cookie: ERIGHTS=mx2FzxxQIipxxfVArtQrcU5h42Cg2IQIqiMe-oehmg24bkzHplCtmgn7zMA==;path=/;domain=.xxx.org Set-cookie: WLSESSION=1579311756.20480.0000; expires=Tue, 29-Dec-2009 13:32:07 GMT; path=/ Location: http://www.xxx.org/xxx.zip 
So what now?

Comment: @safaali: The additional parameter like *path*, *domain* and *expires* are only to restrict the validity of that cookie. You need to validate that information before sending the cookie (e.g. *path* value must be a prefix of the URL path and *domain* a suffix of the URL domain you want to send the cookie to).